# Retain XML code when using PHP XMLWriter::writeElement

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, xmlwriter

I have a mySQL table with fields containing copy that's being turned into XML. Some of the copy in the mySQL fields has bold tags around the words:

`<b>This will be bold</b>, this won't be`.

However, when I come to build my XML document using [XMLwriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php), the copy ends up looking like this:

`&lt;b&gt;This will be bold&lt;/b&gt;, this won't be`

Can anyone advise me on how I can avoid character encoding for these tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing your code needs to use [`XMLWriter::writeRaw`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-write-raw.php) instead of [`XMLWriter::text`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-text.php).

Note that this will only be a good solution if you are confident the content in the database will be proper XML. Otherwise, you will need to first run that content through a DOM parser like [`DOMDocument::loadXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) with the [`DOMDocument::recover`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.recover) flag set, and then export the content with `DOMDocument::saveXML` and pass it to `XMLWriter::writeRaw`.

Comment: XMLWriter::writeRaw did the trick, I have noted your caveat for this solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your copy through `html_entity_decode()`, like this:

```
echo html_entity_decode("&lt;b&gt;This will be bold&lt;/b&gt;, this won't be");
```